# How to automatically change folder & file names in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter-3

I'm preparing all the files for Afghanistan then intending to copy the entire Afghanistan folder and pasting it in other country folders. I have a text editor to change the contents of each file but it wont change the folder & file names.

For example I want the following;

C:\xampp\htdocs\application\views\afghanistan\afcontactus\afcomplaint

\afcontactus\afcomplaint

for Albania changed to;

C:\xampp\htdocs\application\views\albania\alcontactus\alcomplaint

\alcontactus\alcomplaint

and for Algeria changed to;

C:\xampp\htdocs\application\views\algeria\dzcontactus\dzcomplaint

\dzcontactus\dzcomplaint

If CodeIgniter can also change the contents I'll be able to do the lot in one operation.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Are you translating?

Comment: No, all in English. I'm preparing the website for Afghanistan then I want to copy & paste those files into other countries but I need to change the file & folder names. There are too many to do manually.

Comment: This has nothing todo with CodeIgniter. You need a tool like this: http://file-folder-ren.sourceforge.net/